# Mapping local ip address+port to a host name using nginx but no mapping is done

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I need to map a host name along with a port no to a domain name. Like I want `mysite.com` to map to `127.0.0.1:8084`. I installed nginx(to use as reverse proxy server) & added these lines within file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

```
server {
    listen mysite.com:80;
    server_name  mysite.com;
    root 127.0.0.1:8084/;

    location / {

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8084/;
    }
}
```

But there is no impact, no mapping is done even after restarting the ngnix server.

Comment: That root setting is wrong - it should point to a directory, see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root

Comment: Does mysite.com actually resolve to the servers IP? Is anything written to the log files?

Answer (score 5):

Here's small changes to your config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  mysite.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8084/;
    }
}
```

Then just reload/restart nginx and you're done